# Initializing wave form generator to certain frequency

Tags: c, avr

I have small problem with generating sine wave initially with 125 kHz. This seems very simple but it took lot of time from me but i couldn't figure it out what is the problem.  I am using CodeVisionAVR compiler.

I am using ATmega32-A micro controller, AD9833 programmable wave form generator to generate sine wave. I have written the fallowing code.

```
#include <MEGA32.h>
#include <main.h>
#include <interface.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <sleep.h>

 // GLOBAL VARIABLES
 unsigned int i;

 //Status
 unsigned char state = 0;
 unsigned char debug = 0;
 unsigned int status = 0x0010;

 //External variables
 unsigned char Command;
 unsigned int  Param;
 extern unsigned char rx_counter0; 


 //Initialize registers
 void init(void){

    #asm("cli");        //Disable global interrupt

    // Input/Output Ports initialization
    // Port B initialization 
    PORTB=0x00;
    DDRB=0xBF;

    // Port C initialization
    PORTC=0x00;
    DDRC=0xC3;

    // Port D initialization
    PORTD=0x00;
    DDRD=0xFC;

    // USART initialization
    // Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
    // USART Receiver: On
    // USART Transmitter: On
    // USART0 Mode: Asynchronous
    // USART Baud Rate: 9600
    UCSRC=0x86;
    UBRRH=0x00;
    UBRRL=0x67;
    UCSRA=0x00;
    UCSRB=0xD8;
   //UCSRC=0x86;

   // SPI initialisation
   // SPI clock rate fck/16
   // SPI master
   // SPI MSB first
   // SPI CPOL = 1, CPHA = 1
   SPCR=0x5D;
   //PORTB.1 = 1;    //Flash CS high
   PORTB.3 = 1;    //ADC CS high

  //Global enable interrupts
  #asm("sei")
 }

 void runCom(void){

         switch(Command){

                        case(NO_COM):
                            Command = 0;
                            break;

                        case(FREQ):
                            if(Param < 500)
                                SetWGFreq(Param);   
                                Command = 0;
                            break; 

                        case(PHASE):
                            if(Param < 4095)
                                SetWGPhase(Param);
                            Command = 0;
                            break;          
                        default:
                            Command = 0;
                            break;   
                    }
             }

  void main(void){
        status = 0x0010;
        init();                                     //Initialize controller

        SetWGFreq(125);     //Initialize waveformgenerator 125 kH     

        debug = 0;              //Controls output during motor running      
   while (1){

         if(rx_counter0) getCom();                     
         if(Command)     runCom();

          }
       }
   }
   #asm("WDR");        //Reset WD timer 
 }  // EOF "while(1)"
} // EOF "main(void)"


unsigned char spi(unsigned char data) 
{ 
//Start transmision 
SPDR = data; 
//Wait for transmision complete 
while (!(SPSR & 0x80)); 
return SPDR; 
}        



//Sets the waveform generator output to given kHz
void SetWGFreq(unsigned int freq)
{
unsigned long freg;
char fByte0;
char fByte1;
char fByte2;
char fByte3;

freg = (unsigned long)freq*33554.432;   //Number based on a MCLK of 8 MHz
fByte0 = (char)freg;
fByte1 = (char)(freg>>8);
fByte1 = (fByte1 & 0x3F) | 0x40;        //clears bits 15 and 14, then sets for FREQ0
fByte2 = (char)(freg>>14);              //byte1 only has 6 bits, so move over by 8+6
fByte3 = (char)(freg>>22);              //byte1 only has 6 bits, so move over by 8+8+6
fByte3 = (fByte3 & 0x3F) | 0x40;        //clears bits 15 and 14, then sets for FREQ0

SPCR = 0x5A;        //Set SPI to mode 2 and Fosc/64
WG_CS = 0;
while(WG_CS_PIN);   //Wait for chip select pin to go low
spi(0x20);          //Load control register with B28 high
spi(0x00);
spi(fByte1);
spi(fByte0);
spi(fByte3);
spi(fByte2);
WG_CS = 1;
}
```

I am using SPI communication between ATmega32-A and AD9833. I have written one function for setting frequency of the signal and one more function for changing the phase of the signal.

I have written commands in switch case when i enter "FREQ" and frequency value it is generating signal with whatever frequency you entered, same with "PHASE" i am able to change phase of the signal. So i am able to set frequency and phase of the signal successfully using commands.

Now my problem is,

I want to Initialize waveform generator 125 kHz when i run the code. even when power off/on also it should be 125KHz. if user wants to change frequency from 125 to any other he has to use "FREQ" function.
For that purpose I have called " SetWGFreq" function in the main program before entering into the while loop.

> SetWGFreq(125);     //Initialize waveformgenerator 125 kH

I don't know why it was not working.

But when place this function in while loop it is working(intially signal is generating with 125KHz) but "FREQ" is not working. it means after that if i want change frequency of the signal using "FREQ" function, it was not working.

Please help me with this, i couldn't figure out what was the mistake i am doing.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in your question.

Comment: Could it be you are missing to declare `Command` and `Param` `extern`ally?

Comment: @alk even same problem after declaring externally.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to show how `getCom()` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, I would suspect that the problem is not that the call to SetWGFreq() does not work; the problem is that the **first** time does not work.

The function call drives the CS pin low then restores high at end of command
WG_CS = 0;
...
WG_CS = 1;

But the first time through, WG_CS was probably already 0.  The first call is serving just to flush out pre-existing incomplete SPI state.

You can quickly test by simply adding a second call to SetWGFreq().  If that resolves then you know solution.

In general, you would want something during initialize that flushes out any power up garbage.  At minimum a CS cycle should clear any SPI state.  Better send a status command, or reset to establish a known state

You probably fixed this by now, what was the problem?